# How can I move my bar labels to the end of bar that they respectively represent?

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

```
'''Create Chart'''

plt.style.use('seaborn-darkgrid')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

'''Reverse Order of Data Frame'''
sqldata = sqldata.iloc[::-1]
'''Create Chart with reversed dataframe'''
sqldata.plot(x='AccountName',y=['t30','t0'],kind='barh', ax=ax)
ax.set_title(f"FIG Cash Sheet {todaydate}")
ax.set_xlabel('Cash')
ax.set_ylabel('Account')
ax.set_title(f"FIG Cash Sheet {todaydate}")
# y = np.arange(100000)
x = np.arange(len(sqldata))
height = 0.4
width = 0.3
ax.set_xlim(0,35000000)
ax.legend()
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='x')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mmformat)

'''Add bar labels'''
time0 = sqldata.t0/1000000
time30 = sqldata.t30/1000000
rects1 = ax.barh(x + width/2, time0, width)
rects2 = ax.barh(x - width/2, time30, width)
ax.bar_label(rects1,padding=0,fmt="%.2fMM",label_type='edge')
ax.bar_label(rects2,padding=0,fmt='%.2fMM',label_type='edge')
```

Hey guys,

Looking to move my data labels to the end of the bars for each bar. The current code outputs the attached image: [MPLOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXJrO.jpg)

Edit 1: I have already played around with "label_type", setting it as edge, center, or none changes nothing. This leads me to believe I blew something up in my code as those different label types were working previously.

Comment: Try removing `label_type='edge'` in your last 2 lines

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)

# Example data
people = ('Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Slim', 'Jim')
y_pos = np.arange(len(people))
performance = 3 + 10 * np.random.rand(len(people))
error = np.random.rand(len(people))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

hbars = ax.barh(y_pos, performance, xerr=error, align='center')
ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
ax.set_yticklabels(people)
ax.invert_yaxis()  # labels read top-to-bottom
ax.set_xlabel('Performance')
ax.set_title('How fast do you want to go today?')

# Label with specially formatted floats
ax.bar_label(hbars, fmt='%.2f')
ax.set_xlim(right=15)  # adjust xlim to fit labels
```

demo code from [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_label_demo.html)

[image]